# Command line for editing a configuration file value without an interactive editor

Tags: text-processing, command-line, configuration

Many configuration files are based on the format `Key value` or `Key=value` with one line for each of them.
Many packages provide a default configuration file where theses available configuration keys are  already written with their default value and/or are commented.

I'm wondering if there is a tool that allows to change that kind of files without the need to open an interactive editor and more high level than `sed` (possibly built over it).

That would be something as simple as :

```
$ conftool file key value
```

It would find the key in the file, remove the comment sign(s) if any, change the value and save the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as i know there is no generic config line changer tool. i imagine it would be hard to create such a tool because there are so many different config file syntaxes.

if you want to change a specific value in a specific config file then you can write a specialized tool for that specific task.

here are two examples using sed and awk to help you get started

a simple sed command to replace the value of a key for a simple `key value` syntax

```
$ sed 's/^key2 value2$/key2 newvalue2/' config
```

example

```
$ cat config 
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3

$ sed 's/^key2 value2$/key2 newvalue2/' config 
key1 value1
key2 newvalue2
key3 value3
```

but beware: if there are more `key2 value2` lines (possibly in other sections of the config file) then all will be replaced. this is hard to prevent in sed (possible but hard) and easier in awk. see below for an awk command that respects sections.

explanation:

this sed command does roughly the following:

```
for every line:
  if line is "key2 value2":
    print "key2 newvalue2"
```

this sed command `s/pattern/replace/` means: in every line search for `pattern` and if found replace with `replace`. `pattern` can be a normal string or a regex (regular expression).

the `^` and `&` in the regex are called anchors and means beginning of line and end of line respectively. without the anchors this pattern `key2 value2` would also match this line `xkey2 value2x` and the results would be `xkey2 newvalue2x`.

here are some examples how we can change the behaviour with the pattern.

also works with `key=value` syntax

```
$ sed 's/^key2=value2$/key2=newvalue2/' config
```

to just match key regardless of old value

```
$ sed 's/^key2=.*/key2=newvalue2/' config
```

to remove possible comment sign

```
$ sed 's/^#\?key2 value2$/key2 newvalue2/' config
```

to see that something was changed if you redirect the output you can also print to stderr

```
$ sed 's/^#\?key2 value2$/key2 newvalue2/ w /dev/stderr' config > newconfig
```

you can do a lot more with the correct regex. but that would be another answer for another question.

here is an awk script that can also handle config sections

```
/^\[section2\]$/ {
  print
  insection2=1
  next
}
insection2 && /^#?key2=value2$/ {
  print "key2=newvalue2"
  next
}
/^\[.*\]$/ {
  insection2=0
}
1
```

use like this

```
$ awk -f configer.awk config
```

example

```
$ cat config 
[section1]
key1=value1
key2=value2

[section2]
key1=value1
key2=value2

[section3]
key1=value1
key2=value2

$ awk -f configer.awk config 
[section1]
key1=value1
key2=value2

[section2]
key1=value1
key2=newvalue2

[section3]
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

you can also add a verbose output to stderr so you can see what has changed if you redirect the output

```
insection2 && /^#?key2=value2$/ {
  print "key2=newvalue2"
  print "changed line "NR > "/dev/stderr"
  next
}
```

short explanation of awk script

the first rule looks for the `[config2]` section header. it will set the `insection2` flag to true

the second rule looks for the `key2=value2` line. but only if the `insection2` flag is true. it will then print the line with the new value.

the third rule looks for any other section header. it will reset the `insection2` flag to false.

the last rule (the lone `1`) is the "default rule". it will just print the line unchanged.

in pseudo code

```
for every line:
  if line is [section2]:
    note that we are in section2
  else if we are in section2 and line is key2=value2:
    print modified line
  else if line is any other section header:
    note that we are no longer in section2
  else
    print line unchanged
```

Comment: For the sed commands, add some line anchors or word boundaries: this code will match `oldkey2=value2345` and replace `oldkey2=newvalue2345`

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. i anchored all the regexes.